# How to execute command in zsh on statup

Tags: shell, zsh

I need to start zsh and execute the command that it is equivalent to

```
zsh -li
```

and typing `<command><Enter>`.

Adding anything to configuration file is not appropriate, since I need it only in some cases.

Comment: Is it the same command every time or do you want to pass it on the command line as argument to the zsh command?

Comment: @Adaephon Yes I want to pass it as argument to the zsh command.

Comment: But you want to stay in the newly opened shell, so `zsh -c 'command'` is not what you are looking for?

Comment: Have a look at [this question on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/91881/invoke-zsh-having-it-run-a-command-and-then-enter-interactive-mode-instead-of). It seems to be exactly what you are looking for. Aside from the accepted answer [Brandon Thomsons' answer](https://superuser.com/a/230090/276168) might be worth a try.